# VBA Sort Rows by First Letter in Cell Only

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, methods, range

I'm using the following to sort the data by multiple columns.  The problem is that I only want it to sort by the first letter of the text in column AX.

```
With Worksheets("Master")
    With .Range(.Cells(.Range("BorderFirstRow").Row + 1, "A"), _
                .Cells(.Range("BorderLastRow").Row - 1, "ZZ"))
        .Sort Key1:=.Cells(1, "AX"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
              Key2:=.Cells(1, "J"), Order2:=xlAscending, _
              Key3:=.Cells(1, "L"), Order3:=xlAscending, _
              Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo
    End With
End With
```

I've reviewed the Range.Sort method but I'm not finding a SortMethod or XLSortOrder that allows this.  Is it possible with this method and without adding another column to pull only the Left 1st letter?

Comment: So if your data starts with the same first letter, like "AA", "AC", "AB", what order do you want it to be sorted in?

Comment: @kevin Probably this is then defined by Key2.

Comment: I would say adding a temp helper column by VBA code is the the easiest solution.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide sample data ***as text which can be copy/pasted*** and at least a screenshot of your desired results from that data. Be sure your data is representative of the various cases that might exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to create another column to sort by using `Left(cells(i,50).value,1)` to take the first letter of the data from AX. If you really don't want to create another column you may need to either save and restore the data in AX or create your own sort function.

Comment: I'm trying to prevent another column as I already have up to BB that I'm trying to display at once.  I know it can be hidden but I already have several of those for other tasks as well.  I was really hoping this could be summed up into one Macro to prevent complication.

Comment: You could create the column, sort, and then delete the column all within the macro if you want and that way you will not end up with a new column at the end. I might also wrap the macro in `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` followed by `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` so the code runs faster and the user never sees the helper column.

Comment: The "magic" of Power Query is just that you "create" columns, operate on it, then delete all unwanted ones. In a transparent (and efficient) way.

Comment: I have many sorting macros for the columns past AX which are already setup and assigned their columns in VBA.  If I do that, won't it mess them up?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).